# Internal error occured while launching Eclipse RAP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

I am currently using Eclipse 2020-03 and installed eclipse RAP 3.16 using the Install New Software feature. Now when I try to launch the RAP application, the below error is seen.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching RAP_Application".
org.eclipse.pde.internal.launching.launcher.LauncherUtils.clearWorkspace(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V
```

Comment: RAP 3.16 is intended for Eclipse 2021-03. Looks like an API that it uses is not available in your 2020-03 release. According to the RAP site RAP 3.12 is for 2020-03.

Comment: You're right. I was using latest RAP with older eclipse. 
Thank you

Comment: You should file a bug report so that this can be avoided in the future.

Comment: I have raised the bug report in bugszilla.